# What is available for in app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Is it possible to see what is available for purchase with the google in app purchase v3.

I have looked everywhere and I cannot get a hint of how to check if an item you want is available for purchase or not (e.g. I want to have a product in the app at a later time, and I check if I have added it to inapp purchases yet or not, without uploading a new app with those updates or a new database with those updates.

Is this possible, is there a way to query which items are available for purchase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely.

If you have the SKU code of your product, you can query its details using [getSkuDetails()](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails). However, you will need a list of the codes beforehand.

Comment: Yea that's what I thought. Thanks.